# $e$ and $\ln$ : how to derive two equivalent equations

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

When solving the equation

$$150 = 160 - 40 e^{-t/20}$$

I come to a solution that seems natural to me as follows:

\begin{align*}
.25 &= e^{-t/20}\\
\ln(.25) &= -t/20\\
t &= -20 \ln(.25)\\
&= 27.7259.
\end{align*}

However, the textbook gives the same result as

$$t = 40 \ln(2) = 27.7259.$$

Can someone please explain to me how to derive the result from the book?

Regards, Danny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-20 \ln (.25) = -20 \ln (\frac 14) = 20 \ln (4) = 40 \ln 2$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $0.25=\frac 14=2^{-2}$, so $\log (0.25) = -2 \log (2)$

Comment: yes, of course, $ln(1/x) = -ln(x)$ and $ln(a^b) = b ln(a)$ thank you both !!!